# How to define alias for SCSS in Nuxt 3?

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, vite

My project has this structure (only relevant files are shown):

```
.
├── .nuxt
├── src
│   ├── @core
│   │   └── scss
│   │       └── _variables.scss
│   └── styles
│       └── _template.scss
├── nuxt.config.ts
└── package.json
```

Here is how my alias are configured in the `nuxt.config.ts` file:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  srcDir: 'src/',
  alias: {
    '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    '@core': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/@core', import.meta.url))
  }
});
```

In any `.vue` file, this code works perfectly fine:

```html
<style lang="scss">
@forward "@core/scss/variables";
</style>
```

However, inside an `.scss` file, this line

```scss
@forward "@core/scss/variables";
```

throws an error saying that the directory is not resolvable.

It seems that something is missing in the configuration of alias. How can I fix it?

I'm using Nuxt 3.8.2, and I've already installed `sass` dependency, version `1.69.5`.

Comment: use `/<rootDir>/src/@core` instead of `fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/@core', import.meta.url))` work?

Comment: Unfortunately not.